# Am I too weak or are white phantoms too strong?

Tags: dark-souls

I've started a new game as a pyromancer, just defeated the taurus demon in the Undead Burg. However, I was just able to defeat him using the help of a white phantom.
I've tried to beat him serveral times on my own, trying to farm on the enemies every now and then.
After I gave in and summoned a phantom, the fight was too easy. I went to kill the archers, the phantom positioned himself at the other end of the bridge. I went to pull the boss, who then got backstabbed to half-life immediately. I couldn't even hit the boss before the phantom took him down...

Am I too weak at this point or are white phantoms (or this one) stronger than myself?

Comment: How many times have you played the game?

Comment: A lot of phantoms are pretty overpowered for the area their summon sign is in, since many experienced players enjoy showing off. That said, if you tried multiple times, and couldn't defeat him, you probably just need a little more fighting experience. Since most people will encounter Taurus before upgrading their weapons, he is designed to be fairly doable with just the basic starter weapons (in your case the handaxe and pyro flame). If you don't like their movesets, you might find other weapons in undead burg more to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

If the Phantom was effecitvely able to 2-hit the Taurus demon, yeah. They're overlevelled for this area.

You, on the other hand, perhaps just need to take a different approach. The Taurus Demon has a fairly high resistance to fire damage, and since the Pyromancer has a fairly low "armor level" (physical damage resistance), you're actually probably better off using the axe you get instead.

The method of going off the tower to plunge-attack is a legitimate method, safe, and easily repeatable.

Some highly skilled players have managed to beat the game without any levelling at all, so there's technically no such thing as being "underlevelled"; it's just a matter of tactics.

Comment: There are also a very good amount of speedruns/overpowered in 10 minutes videos,  which basically are a guide to be very strong only a few minutes into the game. Also unless you play the HD remake, there are a few bugs which make the game even easier (moveset swap, tumblebuff etc). For the minotaur, lightning is a very good choice of element. You can get the proper resin before having to fight the minotaur